# Removing a specific first item in a string in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have strings such as:

`'THE HOUSE'`

`'IN THE HOUSE'`

`'THE THE HOUSE'`

And I would like to remove 'THE' only if it occurs at the first position in the string.

I know how to remove 'THE' with:

```
gsub("\\<THE\\>", "",  string)
```

And I know how to grab the first word with:

```
"([A-Za-z]+)" or "([[:alpha:]]+)"or "(\\w+)"
```

But no idea how to combine the two to end up having:

`'HOUSE'`

`'IN THE HOUSE'`

`'THE HOUSE'`

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
string <- c("THE HOUSE", "IN THE HOUSE", "THE THE HOUSE")
sub("^THE\\b\\s*", "", string)
## => [1] "HOUSE"        "IN THE HOUSE" "THE HOUSE"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uDC6lV/1) and an [online R demo](https://ideone.com/hszvJP).

**Details**

- `^` - [start of string](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)
- `THE` - a literal substring
- `\\b` - a word boundary (you may keep `\\>` trailing word boundary if you wish)
- `\\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed. I love the demos!